# Ancient Greek term rendered incorrectly as numbers and Latin letters, "01KCDÇ". What is it?

Tags: ancient-greece, hellenistic-greece, classical-greece

In a book I am reading, I've spotted an error and would like to know how to correct it:

> In the Athenian 01KCDÇ, for example, the family was based on a system of individual members which moved out, laterally and hierarchically, from the blood-ties of the immediate relations, into the community.
>
> *[The astrology of family dynamics](https://docero.net/doc/erin-sullivan-the-astrology-of-family-dynamics-215-177oomp2nz)   by Erin Sullivan*

Does anyone  recognize this concept? What could 01KCDÇ be referring to?

Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: Adding some guesses of mine in case it helps. It looks like this word is related to οἶκος (*oikos*) somehow, but I can't tell if it's quite the same. That last letter Ç definitely looks like a ς. The CD part is what's really throwing me off.

Comment: Where did you find this? url? Ttile? ISBN? That might be helpful for people speaking Greek.

Comment: The citation appears to be from an astrology book by Erin Sullivan, [The astrology of family dynamics](https://docero.net/doc/erin-sullivan-the-astrology-of-family-dynamics-215-177oomp2nz).

Comment: Yes, that's the book

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The version on display here is from a bad OCR of the word *oikos*

[image]

Screenshot from Erin Sullivan: *The Astrology of Family Dynamics* 2001 [gBooks](https://books.google.com/books?id=rQs-JRxt588C)

> [The ancient Greek word oikos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oikos) (ancient Greek: οἶκος, plural: οἶκοι; English prefix: eco- for ecology and economics) refers to three related but distinct concepts: the family, the family's property, and the house. Its meaning shifts even within texts, which can lead to confusion.

---

At first, I suspected a really bad online/copy-fraud version of this book, since the term "01KCDÇ" appears in online searches of PDFs. But in this case it seems indeed to be *this* sloppy in a real book on sale version: [gBooks](https://books.google.com/books?id=SH-HfPaMRTIC).

Correct version:

[image]

Ridiculous version:

[image]

Comment: Why does your blockquote use an omicron where the images show an omega?

Comment: @Spencer Both versions are shown 'as found'. WP uses the apparently common spelling, that book: just not. In modern Greek they are the exact same sound, and the omikron variant is surely the more common version ;) — for _oikos._ The omega variant is found in some texts, although apparently in versions like those not using the final-form of sigma as well? If I were to correct that book, I'd go for a plain simple Latin transliteration, if not Latin/English words, to avoid confusion and such 'mistakes' when trying to show off ancient Greek lettering…

Comment: Your answer would be more complete if you pointed that out.